# How to resume a Mavericks download on OS X 10.6?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

I've initiated OS X Mavericks download from the App Store. Upon either re-login or restart, the OS X Mavericks icon in the dock shows that it's paused. Clicking Resume from the context menu doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a usability bug. You have to open the App Store, log-in, and only then will the Resume option work. To resume, you can also click "Download" on the OS X Mavericks line in the Purchases table of the App Store.

Since there's no instant feedback as to whether anything is being downloaded unless your connection is very fast, you can use Activity Monitor to check whether network download seems to be saturated. An alternative is iStat Menus (non-free with 14 day free trial). There, you can not only see that data is downloaded, but you can confirm that it is the `storeagent` process that does the downloading.

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question! The solution isn't at all obvious. Apple really used to be better at usability.

Answer (score 0):

I canceled the download by clicking 'cancel downloading' from the context menu. This did stop the download. Now I am starting download again...

Comment: This could turn into a great answer if it was edited to explain where to click. In launch pad or in finder or from within a specific view of the Mac App Store app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login with your Apple ID in the App Store.
2. Search for 'mavericks' in the search bar.
3. Select Mavericks on the App Store than click Download to resume.